# The SyncAdapter is pending always on the Android 6

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I wrote a custom `SyncAdapter` and `SyncStatusObserver` by a Google sample and it works perfectly on old devices. But on the Android 6 it has a pending status always.
I checked in a debug mode my adapter finishes a work and a observer called with a active status is `false` but a pending status is `true` all same.

It's my code in the synchronization status observer:

```
Account account = getAccount();

if (account == null) {
    return;
}

boolean syncActive = ContentResolver.isSyncActive(account, SyncService.CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
boolean syncPending = ContentResolver.isSyncPending(account, SyncService.CONTENT_AUTHORITY);
final boolean isLoading = syncActive || syncPending;
```

I call this code in

```
private SyncStatusObserver mStatusObserver = new SyncStatusObserver() {

   @Override
   public void onStatusChanged(final int which) {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                onSyncStatusChanged(which);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

To request a synchronization I call:

```
public static void refresh(Account account, Bundle extras) {
    extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_MANUAL, true);
    extras.putBoolean(ContentResolver.SYNC_EXTRAS_EXPEDITED, true);
    ContentResolver.requestSync(account, SyncService.CONTENT_AUTHORITY, extras);
}
```

Someone has any ideas why it doesn't work on Android 6? I will glad any logical suggestions because I really can't understand already.

**P.S.** `Account` isn't null I checked.